# UPGRADED QUESTION ON BAD TOML FILE READING

Tags: stellar.toml

Yesterday i posted about my toml file and the checker showing wrong tokens I went throught the c panel and in the back up showed the old toml file so i fixed that problem and now it still shows the wrong token in the well known folder it is show ["GAH7HEJAOTPPLSOXYI5L2IFVVNRFGZKUQ5E4U626YWTFBPAB6V4DOZAD" and it is supposed to be showing ACCOUNTS=["GB2ZIXMIDDBX3DPT3HX2SALHPNPKMJRNN6CNN54O7O2DXFEKQPCXE7IY"]

Now when on the same checker if you click the url show in the pic below where it say PARSE IT WILL SHOW THE CORRECT TOKENS AND INFO BUT AT THE BOTTOM STILL SHOWS WARNING, ALSO NOW WHEN I TRY TO CHECK THE STATUS OF THE TOKEN IN THE STELLAR LAB ASSEST CHECKER IT SAYS NO SUCH ASSEST BUT I CELARLT HAVE THEM IN MY WALLET AND THE ISSUING ACCOUNT SHOWING IT ISSUED THEM ON LIVE NET AND THEY ARE GOOD [image]

Comment: Guess your fix was a DNS issue and you have been to impatient waiting for its propagation? Whatever, looks good now. I think you only have to remove one of the images.

Comment: Actually the stellar toml checker is not reading it correctly  it sitll shows that it is not looking at the url correcttly My url was showing joinGrowth.org with a capitaol g then is supposed to be lower case so I changed it yesterday and still it will not remove the warning but not the big problem it was so im sure it will catch up sooner or later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you created the digital asset and uploaded the toml file you still had the new toml file in the wrong area we went in last week and removeed the old toml file that was still reading that info, uploaded the new toml file into its place and is working great. So when you return from vaca you can remove the question it is all taken care off.  Dev